# Operating on JSON returned from http.get in Angular 4.3

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

In my my, I am attempting to serve dynamic form controls via JSON to a form builder similar to the dynamic forms tutorial at angular.io. I am having trouble operating on JSON data returned from an http.get() request. I can console.log the whole object, but if I try to log a sub-object, I get "undefined" in the console.

Here is my component file:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

dataSource: Observable<any>;
questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
results: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.dataSource = this.http.get('/questions');
}

ngOnInit() {
      this.dataSource.subscribe(
          data => {
              this.results = data['contactInfo'];
              console.log(this.results[0].controlType);
              this.results.forEach((item: QuestionBase<any>) => {
                  if(item.controlType == 'text') {
                      console.log(item.controlType);
                      this.questions.push(new TextQuestion(item));
                  }
                  else if(item.controlType == 'dropdown') {
                      console.log(item.controlType);
                      this.questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(item));
                  }
              });

              console.log(this.questions);
          },
          err => {
              console.log("Cannot get JSON data. Error Code: %s, URL: %s",
                  err.status, err.url)
          },
          () => console.log('Done')
      );
   }
}
```

In the data => {} callback, if I console.log(request), the console displays the entire object just fine. I can even read sub-objects in the template. But, if I try to console.log or do any other thing with sub-objects as in the code above, e.g. the forEach() method, I get "undefined" on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the JSON snippet:

```
{
"contactInfo": [
{
  "key": "firstName",
  "globalLabel": "First Name",
  "controlType": "text",
  "required": "true",
  "order": "1"
},
{
  "key": "lastName",
  "globalLabel": "Last Name",
  "controlType": "text",
  "required": "true",
  "order": "2"
},
{
  "key": "streetAddress",
  "globalLabel": "Street Address",
  "controlType": "text",
  "required": "true",
  "order": "3"
}, ...}]
```

Edit #2 I had failed to restart my Node server after updating the JSON file to read "controlType" over an earlier version that used simply "type." I figured the server would automatically serve the newly edited and saved file, but it seems as though one must restart the server in order to do this. ISSUE CLOSED

Comment: could you provide `/questions` example response?

Comment: If I use `console.log(this.results);` I get the following: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {key: "firstName", globalLabel: "First Name", type: "text", required: "true", order: "1"}1: {key: "lastName", globalLabel: "Last Name", type: "text", required: "true", order: "2"}2: ... continuing for all sub-objects.

Comment: disregard my previous answer. i was not aware of the `HttpClient`

Comment: @EricJobe I don't see controlType in the results that you posted in your above comment. what is the exact console.log that is returning undefined?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be reading old JSON that has since been corrected. I'm at a loss as to why the server isn't sending the new JSON file. Working on it.

Comment: Well, color me embarrassed. I had updated my JSON file to read "controlType" over an earlier "type" but had not restarted my Node server since the update thinking that it would server the updated file automatically. After restarting the server, the code works as intended. Thanks for everyone's help. Sometimes just another set of eyes is all that's needed.